# How is keras predict working with datasets

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am new in using tf datasets with keras. Since you just handover one object, I don't understand what actually happens. If I handover a dataset to model predict, how does it know how and what elements to use from this object? Since a dataset of complex structure which inherits many kind of structures and levels I think, what happens if I take a dataset which as more "columns" than the dataset which was trained on. Are somehow the structure, names or levels saved during training from the dataset to remember when making predictions?

Answer (score 0):

if `tf.keras.Model.fit()` receives `tf.dataset()` as input - it assumes that the dataset returns a tuple of either `(inputs, targets)` or            `(inputs, targets, sample_weights)`. Now, inputs part itself may be a complex structure of sub-inputs (like tuple of image and label for conditional VAE for instance).
If the dataset does not fit your model inputs - `fit()` will just fail.
See [comment to fit() function in the TF source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L832-L834)

Comment: My model was trained on batched dataset, but I can do predictions of a dataset which is not bacthed. Why is this working? In the example of https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#training_workflows, when you don't bacth the prediction dataset you get an error, because of wrong input shapes.

Comment: Also I just saw that my dataset input is a dictionary where the keys are the feature names. So tf.keras fit also works with datasets where the inputs are dictionaries?

Comment: Now my question. If this is the case, does the order of the keys in the prediction dataset need to be the same like the trained dataset? Or the keras somehow save the key names? What if my prediction dataset is of different structure type, like tuples instead of the dictionary? Will it work?

Comment: pls add an example of model trained with dictionary feed, preferably in Colab. It will be easier to answer, referring to specific features of your model.

Comment: I just asked generally if the datatype and "order" of inputs int the dataset tuple should be the same? especially the order of keys if a dict is used?

Comment: order of data should match the order of inputs in the model.